# Why does Augeas Puppet resource type need 3 arguments for defnode?

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas

I'm trying to add or update a user in an xml config file using augeas resource type in Puppet, here the manifest:

```
  augeas { "nexus_user_newadmin":
    lens    => "Xml.lns",
    incl    => "security.xml",
    root    => "/usr/local/nexus/conf",
    changes => [
      "defnode user /files/security.xml/security/users/user[id/#text='newadmin']",
      "set $user/id/#text 'newadmin'",
      "set $user/firstName/#text 'first name'",
      "set $user/lastName/#text 'last name'",
      "set $user/password/#text 'passhere'",
      "set $user/status/#text 'active'",
      "set $user/email/#text 'test@domain.com'",
    ],
  }
```

The xml file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<security>
          <users>
            ...
            <user>
              <id>deployment</id>
              <firstName>Deployment</firstName>
              <lastName>User</lastName>
              <password>somepasshere</password>
              <status>active</status>
              <email>changeme1@yourcompany.com</email>
            </user>
          </users>
</security>
```

I get the error following when I run the manifest:

```
Main/Augeas[nexus_user_newadmin]: Could not evaluate: missing string argument 3 for defnode
```

It looks like the command defnode needs 3 mandatory arguments when used from puppet, but only 2 (and 1 optional) when used from augtool. ([see my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338722/create-or-update-a-section-in-xml-file-with-augeas))

How can I overcome this limitations in augeas implementation in Puppet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several issues there.

First, while `defnode` takes an *optional* third argument (a value) in `augtool`, this argument is mandatory in Ruby/Puppet. You can however set it to an empty string.

Second, the `$user` variable is parsed by Puppet because you're using double quotes, so Augeas doesn't receive it (it's empty). You must either use single quotes or escape the dollar sign. In general, it is recommended to use single quotes in Puppet unless you need variables to be expanded.

Third, it'll be better to use `incl` and `lens` rather than `root`. You will benefit from an automatic `context` in Puppet, too:

```puppet
augeas { 'nexus_user_newadmin':
  lens    => 'Xml.lns',
  incl    => '/usr/local/nexus/conf/security.xml',
  changes => [
    'defnode user security/users/user[id/#text="newadmin"] ""',
    'set $user/id/#text "newadmin"',
    'set $user/firstName/#text "first name"',
    'set $user/lastName/#text "last name"',
    'set $user/password/#text "passhere"',
    'set $user/status/#text "active"',
    'set $user/email/#text "test@domain.com"',
  ],
}
```

Comment: looks like it creates a new user section every time the manifest is run. how to avoid this ? I mean, update the already existing user or add a new one if it's not there.

Comment: It shouldn't. At least, it doesn't for me. Are you sure you copied the code properly (including, and especially, the quotes)?